prepare statement and notice appear: undefined index in php
i'm trying to make prepare statement in php.
my code as below;
<?php

include ('vkdbconnect.php');

//Define variables
$pemeriksa1Err = "";
$pemeriksa2Err = "";
$lokasiErr = "";
$dateErr = "";
$timeErr = "";

function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty($_POST["pemeriksa1"])){
        $pemeriksa1Err = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $pemeriksa1 = test_input($_POST["pemeriksa1"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["pemeriksa2"])){
        $pemeriksa2Err = "Name is required";
    } else{
        $pemeriksa2 = test_input($_POST["pemeriksa2"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["lokasi"])){
        $lokasiErr = "Location is required";
    } else{
        $lokasi_periksa = test_input($_POST["lokasi"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["date"])){
        $dateErr = "Date is required";
    } else{
        $tarikh_periksa = test_input($_POST["date"]);
    }

    if(empty($_POST["time"])){
        $timeErr = "Time is required";
    } else{
        $masa_periksa = test_input($_POST["time"]);
    }

}
if(empty($pemeriksa1Err) && empty($pemeriksa2Err) && 
    empty($lokasiErr) && empty($dateErr) && empty($timeErr))

{

    $sql = "INSERT into maklumat_pemeriksa 
                    (pemeriksa1, pemeriksa2, tarikh_periksa, 
                     masa_periksa,   lokasi_periksa) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters

        $stmt->bind_param("sssss",  $pemeriksa1, $pemeriksa2, 
                                    $tarikh_periksa, $masa_periksa, 
                                    $lokasi_periksa);


        // Set the parameters values and execute the statement again to insert another row 

        $pemeriksa1 = $_REQUEST["pemeriksa1"];
        $pemeriksa2 = $_REQUEST["pemeriksa2"];
        $tarikh_periksa = $_REQUEST["date"];
        $masa_periksa = $_REQUEST["time"];
        $lokasi_periksa = $_REQUEST["lokasi"];

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "<script> alert('Records inserted successfully'); </script";
    }
    else {

        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . $conn->error;

    }

    // Close statement

    $stmt->close();

    // Close connection

    $conn->close();
}
else{

}

?>

this my HTML/PHP form;
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {

?>

<?php
include ('maklumat_pemeriksa.php');
?>

<?php 
include ('../user_vk/vkuserpage.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Maklumat Pemeriksa Kenderaan</title>
<!--Google Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap"      rel="stylesheet">
<!--Stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vkform_maklumat_pemeriksa_style_1.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>PEMERIKSAAN KENDERAAN STATUS VINTAJ / KLASIK</h1><hr/>
    
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  enctype='multipart/form-data'   method="post">

    <p>1. MAKLUMAT PEMERIKSA</p><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <label for="name1">Nama dan Jawatan</label>
                <input type="text" name="pemeriksa1"  placeholder="">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $pemeriksa1Err;?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <label for="name2">Nama dan Jawatan</label>
                <input type="text" name="pemeriksa2"  placeholder="">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $pemeriksa2Err;?></span> 
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <label for="date">Tarikh Pemeriksaan</label>
                <input type="date" name="date">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $dateErr;?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <label for="time">Masa Pemeriksaan</label>
                <input type="time"  name="time" placeholder="">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $timeErr;?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <label for="lokasi">Lokasi Pemeriksaan</label>
                <textarea name="lokasi"  placeholder="" rows="1"></textarea>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $lokasiErr;?></span>
            </div>
        </div><br><br>

        <button type="submit" class="button" name="submit">Simpan</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" name="submit" value="submit"    onclick="location.href='index_maklumat_kenderaan.php'">Seterusnya</button>
    </form>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php 
 }else{
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit();
 }
 ?>

unfortunately the notice appear which is said"

Notice: Undefined index: pemeriksa2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\vkform\maklumat_pemeriksa.php on line 75


Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\vkform\maklumat_pemeriksa.php on line 76


Notice: Undefined index: time in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\vkform\maklumat_pemeriksa.php on line 77


Notice: Undefined index: lokasi in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\vkform\maklumat_pemeriksa.php on line 78

i try to find the solution but is not successful yet. what actually my mistake in my code.? i'm apologize if my explanation is not good enough.

Move the insert into the block where you check if the request is a post request. You're attempting to insert into the database every time you load the page, no matter if it's via GET or POST

And get rid of test_input() its an ancient function that was not an good when it was first posted. And unneeded if you prepare queries

Also if you think that <span class="error"><?php echo $pemeriksa1Err;?></span> these lines will load data into the Input fields, they will not
